# Does using # in URL make difference in SEO

Tags: seo

I would like to know that whether using of # in the URL is going to effect SEO.

For example

http://www.example.com/index.php#page-1

http://www.example.com/index.php#page-2

Both the links have UNIQUE CONTENTS (Contents of the page #page-1 is different from that of #page-2)

Are the pages going to be interpreted as different pages by Google?

Comment: And could any one specify whether there is any method to rewrite the URL http://www.example.com/index.php#page-1 as http://www.example.com/pages/page-1

Comment: You need to follow Google's solution for making dynamic pages crawlable. Otherwise, google will not read dynamic content. http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/getting-started.html

Answer (score 1):

Generally, Google indexes URLs excluding the hash part. This is because it's official use was to indicate a location on a page, not a new page. With AJAX it's use has changed.

You may sometimes see #ed links in Google search results but they are only shown as "jump to" links within the description of another result. They have to be standard anchor links for this to work.

Google offer the hash bang (#!) solution as a hack to help them index your content as if they were multiple pages. Not sure if any other search engine decided to support this. This is what Maris suggested.

The newer option is to change your URLs to not use the hash and use poststate() instead to support your dynamic content. This may not work with older browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly - Google is much better at reading dynamic content than in the past. However, 
as this answer states the correct approach is to create a static mirror:
[Does Google's crawler index asynchronously loaded elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7640004/does-googles-crawler-index-asynchronously-loaded-elements)