# Does Google's crawler index asynchronously loaded elements?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, web-crawler, google-crawlers

I've built some widget for websites which is asynchronously loaded after the page is loaded:

```
<html>
    <head>...</head>
    <body>
        <div>...</div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            (function(){
                var ns = document.createElement("script");
                ns.type = "text/javascript"; 
                ns.async = true;
                ns.src = "http://mydomain.com/myjavascript.js";
                var s = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
                s.parentNode.insertBefore(ns, s);
            })();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Is there anyway to notify Google's crawler to index the page only after the page is fully loaded (after the async JavaScript modified the HTML)?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2434445/does-google-crawl-ajax-content?

Comment: Don't know the answer to your question, tough your page should have full content and be browsable even without scripts.

Comment: No, it's not a duplicate - it's a different scenario.

Answer (score 6):

No. You have to set up static mirror pages for asynchronous content. See here:
http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/getting-started.html

Answer (score 4):

Things have evolved since then:

> - Google crawls and indexes all content that was injected by javascript.
> - Google even shows results in the SERP that are based on asynchronously
>   injected content.
> - Google can handle content from httpRequest().
>
> (...)
>
> - Dynamically updated meta
>   elements get crawled and indexed, too.

Source: http://www.centrical.com/test/google-json-ld-and-javascript-crawling-and-indexing-test.html